# React Typescript linter that replaces single quotes with double on push to git

Tags: reactjs, typescript, code-formatting, linter

Do any of you know a linter for React TypeScript, that replaces single quotes with double quotes on push to git.
So next time someone pulls the project down, there is only double quotes.

Comment: can use something like `husky` and `eslint` on "precommit" have a rule that edit the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this scenario currently implemented using [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) and [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint).

In the `pre-commit` file from husky, I have this command

```
eslint ./src/. --fix
```

And in `.eslintrc` this rule

```
"quotes": [
    "error",
    "double",
    {
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
    }
]
```

Eslint with the `--fix` flag will try to fix what it cans things like adding semicolons or updating quotes. With the rule I'm saying: I want all quotes to be double quotes but allow me to use template literals.

This does not affect react props you can still have props like

When running a commit command, husky will trigger the hook and add double quotes so the commit will have the changes.